# How to exit zoom cleanly?

Tags: zoom-meeting

If you click the close button on zoom, the window disappears but the process is still running. I find that highly annoying and it makes re-showing the zoom window again difficult under many circumstances.

So I resort to

```
killall zoom
```

Is there a simpler way to cleanly exit zoom?

Comment: Have you tried Ctrl-Q? It is the most common quit shortcut on Ubuntu AFAIK.

Comment: @Ginnungagap Yes I have.

Comment: Was trying to find a way to kill zoom without interacting with a mouse, seems that killall is the best option in that case. No shortcuts from Zoom are avail for such a mundane task

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It moves up to the tray in the top right corner, you can click on the icon and click "exit".

[image: Zoom Meeting App in the tray]

Comment: This is what I was looking for. However I don't get that icon. Probably related to my desktop settings. I'll wait for a little longer before I accept this answer.

Comment: Ok this works for me if I disable user themes and activate the ubuntu appindicators extension.

Comment: Good to hear I could help :)

Comment: What version of Zoom? I have 5.3.465578.0920 and when I click the close button Zoom just exits, the icon in the top panel disappears as well and there is no Zoom process left running.