# How to exit zoom without going to the task bar

Tags: unity, taskbar, zoom-meeting

I am using `ubuntu 20.04` with Unity desktop.

I use zoom version `5.8.0 (16)`

I know that
[[How to exit zoom cleanly?]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1259472/how-to-exit-zoom-cleanly)

this is the solution for cleanly exiting from zoom. What I want to know, is how to do this, when I quit zoom.

`When closed, minimize window to the notification are instead of the task bar`

Does not work. When I close the zoom. I want zoom to termninate all of its processes.

How can I achieve this? Ideally, when I quit zoom, I do not want this application to be staying in the task bar (the bar at the top) of ubuntu.

This feature used to work as intended in the previous version (I forgot which, but probably two or three updates back)

Comment: Why did you add the tag unity? Do you use the Unity desktop?

Comment: Yes, I'm using 20.04 with unity desktop.

Comment: I wonder whether this behavior depends on desktop variant or Zoom version, or both? I have GNOME Flashback desktop and Zoom version 5.3.465578.0920 and when I click the close button Zoom just exits, the icon in the top panel disappears as well and there is no Zoom process left running.

Comment: @raj This feature used to work in the previous version but after update, it seemed to be buggy. I use 5.8.0 (16),

Comment: So it looks like a bug in Zoom, does Zoom provide any way to report it?

Comment: @raj Ah yes, now you mentioned it, indeed it is. I will report it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Run the command `killall zoom` in a terminal. This will terminate all zoom processes, even if a meeting is going on. If you want to make it even faster, you could bind a shortcut key to run this command. Gnome allows you to do this, I don't know about unity.